# Re-installing MySQL server 8.0 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, mysql

I needed to purge an installation of MYSQL using the following:

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server
sudo apt purge mysql-server
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt remove dbconfig-mysql
```

Everything seemed to purge ok.

Trying to reinstall I get the following errors after the update file listings:

```
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ... 
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present) 
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server: 
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory) 
mysqld: [ERROR] Stopped processing the 'includedir' directive in file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at l
ine 20. 
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted! 
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgr
ade issues. 
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry. 
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure): 
installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 1 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server: 
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however: 
 Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet. 

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a pre
vious failure. 
             Errors were encountered while processing: 
mysql-server-8.0 
mysql-server 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I reviewed the wiki link, no help. I saw a similar post here from three years ago tried the 'apt install -f' as recommended, again no help.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to remove mysql make sure it is turned off using `sudo systemctl stop mysql` and then try to issue the commands again.

after you stop MySQL service you can run `systemctl status mysql` to make sure it turned off.

let me know if it worked.

[other solution]

Create the directory from the error message.

`sudo mkdir -p /etc/mysql/conf.d/`

Create a new `mysql.cnf` file and write `[mysql]` into it.

`echo "[mysql]" | sudo tee /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`

And reconfigure the packages.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: I checked to make sure mysql was off; inactive and dead.

Comment: follows directions and now systenctl shows my sql is avtive so it looks like it has worked....Thanks for the help

Comment: any thought on now setting the root password?

Comment: @trekerj there is no need to set a `root` password. MySQL can be accessed from the command line with `sudo mysql`, which will log you in as root. From there, create yourself an admin account that you use with other applications. This reduces the risk of accidentally ruining databases. If the system is a server accessed over the internet, *not* using `root` will add another layer of defence in the event someone hacks the application and tries to damage/exploit/steal your data.

Comment: I'm in Thank you again